# "Sub-process gzip returned an error code (1)", how to fix?

Tags: apt, dpkg

when i try,

```
ali@ali-office:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 update-notifier : Depends: update-notifier-common (= 0.147) but 0.147.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

And i trying

```
ali@ali-office:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  update-notifier
The following packages will be upgraded:
  update-notifier
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/56,0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Sub-process gzip returned an error code (1)
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/update-notifier_0.147.1_amd64.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libgcc1:amd64': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
ali@ali-office:~$
```

how i solve this problem?

Comment: Please execute `dpkg --audit`.

Comment: Your disk drive appears to be failing.  Check the SMART status in the disk utility.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal ,and type this

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt-utils
```

then try again.

Comment: ali@ali-office:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt-utils
[sudo] password for ali: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 update-notifier : Depends: update-notifier-common (= 0.147) but 0.147.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your package got an error while downloading. You should clean your cache and try again:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If the error continues, you may switch repositories.

Comment: i tryed but the error continues